# How to close vote on Stack Overflow and move the question to other Stack Exchange sites (e.g. apple.stackexchange.com)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

Today one guy asked a Mac OS-related question on Stack Overflow. Here is the link of the question: *https://stackoverflow.com/q/41390712/468724*

I want to mark it for closure and move it to http://apple.stackexchange.com, but on the options list there was no way to select this site apart from Super User and Server Fault

How can I chose http://apple.stackexchange.com?

Here is the screenshot of the options:

[image]

#### Also the *This question belongs on other site in the Stack Exchange network* has following options:

[image]

Comment: Please ask questions specific to stack overflow on meta stack overflow.